# The question 'Mathematical work of Jonathan Gleason' disappeared

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

The question

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291518/mathematical-work-of-jonathan-gleason

was deleted by some unknown person, not long after Jonathan Gleason passed away. I am shocked with the level of disrespect here. Can someone restore it?

Comment: MathOverflow is not a repository of memorials or obituary material.  It is a question and answer forum more about mathematics than about mathematicians.  If you want to show respect to both Jonathan Gleason and to the purposes of this forum,  continue Gleason's work by studying it and asking a question of appropriate (usually narrow and specific) scope for this forum.  Gerhard "We Welcome Good Mathematical Questions" Paseman, 2018.07.19.

Comment: It is always sad to hear of the loss of a young person.  I don't think any disrespect was intended.   The site is really focussed on questions in mathematics, and exceptions are not often made.

Comment: I removed the bug tag because clearly there was no bug, and replaced it with the discussion tag in view of the only actual question, "Can someone restore it?" (Of course "someone can" in the sense that the ability exists, but I'm pretty sure no one will.)

Answer (score 10):

Disrespect to whom? I don't think it was disrespect to anyone, certainly not Jonathan Gleason. At most it expresses a firm belief that the question is off-topic for MathOverflow.

But as I said in a comment there, announcements of someone's passing have occasionally found a more lasting home at meta. (See for example the discussion at [Grothendieck's passing](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1978/grothendiecks-passing), or for someone not as well known, [Jean-Christophe Yoccoz](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2981/jean-christophe-yoccoz/2986#2986)). (Note however that agreement that such postings are a good idea might not be universal.)

Seeing that you and YYY (who for all I know are the same person) feel very strongly about this, you could try writing something in Jonathan's memory in an answer here. I can't guarantee that the entire community would find this acceptable, but the options here are probably limited anyway.

On reflection, there *is* precedent in saying something commemorative about the passing of MO users specifically, for example http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1218/sad-news-about-torsten-ekedahl/. So my own feeling is that you could probably go ahead and write something here, if you are so moved. I join others in expressing condolences.

Comment: Still no response on whom, for what reason deleted the post.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's particularly a secret. Users YCor, j.c., and Stefan Kohl voted to delete. No one is under obligation to say why they vote as they do, and by writing in a hostile or angry fashion as you have, you are lessening the odds any of them will respond. But I think my own surmise (in the first paragraph) is probably on target.

Comment: I see from an earlier cached version that some comments of the OP have been deleted (either by the OP themselves or by others). I only mention this to put Todd's comment in context